# Finding the timing of the program by using timeit function in python

Tags: python

I have 2 different programs. First is called prob1.py which calculates Fibonacci numbers. Second one is called prob2.py which calculates Fibonacci with using memoisation. In third program called prob3.py, I'm trying to print out (n, timing for fib(n)) for prob1.py and (n, timing for MemoFib(n)) for prob2.py range between (0,40).

prob1.py is

```
import sys

def fib(n):
   if n == 0:
     return (1)
   elif n == 1:
     return (1)
   else:
     return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

def main():
result = int(sys.argv[1])
print(fib(result))
main()
```

and prob2.py is

```
import sys

array = [0]*101

def MemoFib(n):
if n<=1:
    return 1
else:
    if(array[n-1]==0):
        array[n-1] = MemoFib(n-1)
    if(array[n-2]==0):
        array[n-2] = MemoFib(n-2)
    array[n] = array[n-1] + array[n-2]
    return array[n]

def main():
array = [0]*101   # clears the memo between runs
if int(sys.argv[1]) <= 100:
  print(MemoFib(int(sys.argv[1])))
else:
  print('Enter a value between 0 and 100')
main()
```

I have the following codes to call these 2 programs to print out what I need however I can't fit it into my codes. Could you fix it, please? If the following code doesn't work, I can use something else too. All I need is to print out (n, Fib(n)) and (n, MemoFib(n)) by using timeit function.

```
mytime = timeit.Timer( 'fib(0,40)', 'from prob1 import fib' )
delta = mytime.timeit( 40 )
print "40 runs of fib( 1000000 ) took: " + str( delta ) + " seconds."
print ''

setupStr = 'from prob1 import fib'
setupStr += '; import anotherFile'
mytime = timeit.Timer( 'list_concat( anotherFile.a, anotherFile.b)',     setupStr )
print 'calling list_concat from cell.py on a, b, from foo.py:'
delta = mytime.timeit( 5 )
print "1 run of MemoFib( a, b ) took: " + str( delta ) + " seconds."
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling the functions from _inside_ the functions themselves. And the indentation of the code is incorrect.

Comment: Well prob1.py and prob2.py work perfectly. The codes for prob3.py might have identation errors but that's fine. I just need an answer. I can fix the indentation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Timer('fib(0,40)', 'from prob1 import fib')` you are setting up the timer to call `fib` with two arguments which will give you a TypeError telling you that. Instead run the timers in a for loop in `prob3.py`

EDIT - I have now tested this and know it can be executed.

```
import timeit

repeats = 100
run_code = 'fib(%d)' # formatting mark to enter each time
for n in range(40):
    # you can just call the .timeit() function from the module
    mytime = timeit.timeit(run_code % n, 'from prob1 import fib', number=repeats)
    print ("fib(%d) repeated %d times took %f seconds"%(n,repeats,mytime))

# similar for other one
```

Comment: I get this error this time:
  
File "prob3.py", line 5
    mytime = timeit.timeit(run_code%n, 'from prob1 import fib,
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: yes I missed a quote, Rushy Panshal has corrected the mistake, try again

Comment: another one now which is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prob3.py", line 5, in <module>
    mytime = timeit.timeit(run_code % n, 'from prob1 import fib',
NameError: name 'timeit' is not defined

Comment: then just `import timeit` at beginning of code, I edited answer to reflect that

Comment: Nope. it didn't work again:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prob3.py", line 8, in <module>
    number=repeats)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 230, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer).timeit(number)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 136, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6
    fib(0}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sorry I didn't take the time to put  `prob1.py` on my computer, would have prevented a lot of really silly mistakes on my part, now I am certain that it will run correctly provided there is a module called `prob1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101738/discussion-between-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen-and-kafkef89).

Comment: I tried to contact you in discussion chat. Sorry I have never used this before. Did you get my message?